# SQlDependency Get only updated rows from database

Tags: signalr, sqldependency

I would like to get only updated rows from database using SignalR and SQLDependency.

The status column of a table can be updated from multiple applications. What I need is that when this status column gets updated, I need my application to get that record for which the status is updated in real time.
I'm trying to use SQLDependency and SignalR.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you in control of the other applications?

Comment: No,
I'm not in control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might have misunderstood how SQLDependency works.

After an in depth research, I came to understand that the database just notify the subscriber(s) that there is a change in the area of interest (area of interest can are columns in the select list and tables in the from clause of the query.

Whenever there is a change, the database notifies the subscribers and it is up to the subscribers to define their query to get only the changes.

I hope this helps someone out there.